# Determine Java application type

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, servlets

I have been given a Java application to maintain and a little confused as to what type of java application it is.  The application is quite complex with numerous packages, uses Hibernate and runs on Tomcat.

There is NO servlet class and so no doGet or doPost methods etc and no front end in JSP for example, however it uses `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` and in the tomcat\lib folder there is an "servlet-api.jar".  Upon looking at the Java classes there is one in particular with web service and web method annotations so is the class with web service end points but there is no "MAIN" method in this class.  Also there is a WSDL file in the `WebContent\WEB-INF\wsdl` location

I have determined that it uses the `javax.servlet.http.HttpSession` for controlling the session and uses session parameters and some of the imports for the Java class that has the web service annotations are;

```
import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.jws.HandlerChain;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import javax.xml.ws.WebServiceContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
```

I have done work with servlets and java web services before but I suppose the question I am asking is - is this a web service application using a servlet api for the HTTP session aspects or is this a Java servlet using JWS components to provide web service end points?

Here is examples of two of the annotations in the relevant Java class;

```
@WebService(targetNamespace = *manager won't allow me to show anymore of this*

@WebMethod
public String findPrice( ......
```

Comment: Who gave you this application? Does the organization that is using / supporting this have any information for you?

Comment: It must be a web service. Can you show us the annotations please ?

Comment: @ControlAltDel Thanks for response.  It was an application built for the organisation some time ago by someone who has went elsewhere and left little in the way of documentation

Comment: @jr593 Thanks for response.  I have added a little  more on the annotations